# How to remove duplicites from a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have these strings in Java

```
String s1 = "Chicago/London/London/London/Paris";
String s2 = "London/London/London/Paris";
String s3 = "Prague/London/London/London";
String s4 = "London/London";
```

Which regular expression should I use in replaceAll function to make "Chicago/London/Paris", "London/Paris", "Prague/London" and "London" from these strings? Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried doing? And why do you think that regular expressions are the correct tool for this?

Comment: From what it looks like, java String is not the best way to store it. One thought is to split it, put it into a Set, thus eliminating duplicates automatically, and, in case you really need this as a String, join it again using '/'.

Comment: Something like this will do it:
new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s1.split("/"))))

Comment: You should at least consider rephrasing your question, to at least make it clearer what you are trying to match on to begin with!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to handle this yourself.
EDIT: optimized in accordance to @UnholySheep's comment.
EDIT: following @Pshemo's comment, both java 7/8 versions were improved.

```
public String removeDubs(String input) {
    String[] parts = input.split("/");
    Set<String> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(parts));
    return String.join("/", unique);
}
```

EDIT: or if you are using java 8:

```
public String removeDubsV8(String input) {
    return Arrays.stream(input.split("/"))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
}
```

Comment: The `StringBuilder` (and `substring`) usage is unnecessary, you can just do `String.join("/", unique);` instead